# WCF Language Header

Tags: wcf, internationalization

I have a WCF service, and I need to receive a language code (EN for English, or DE for Deutsch, or IT for Italian) to internationalize the result provided by all method of my WCF service. Below is a simplified version of my WCF service and method, and the client I use. And I need to translate the result of the method depending on a language code I retrieve from a header of the request.

```
 //IMyService
 [ServiceContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
 public interface IMyService
 {
   [OperationContract]
   string MyFunction(string myParameter);
 }


 //MyService
 public class MyService : IMyService
 {
     public string MyFunction(string myParameter)
     {
            // Here I need to be able to detect the code language from the incoming request, and somehow to be able to translate 'Couleur' from the specified language...
            return myParameter + "_Couleur";
     }
 }
```

And I have the following WCF Client, which calls the WCF service like that:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceReference.MyService myService = new ServiceReference.MyService();

        // Calling the method MyFunction with parameter 'AAA'
        string result = myService.MyFunction("AAA"); // result = 'AAA_Couleur'
    }
```

And I do not know how to achieve this in WCF, and how to pass a header containing the language code from the client?

I tried to use from the client
var msgHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Language", "", "EN", false);
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(msgHeader);

And to retrieve the code from the WCF service but with no luck.

Any ideas would be greatly appreaciated.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Message inspector, On the client side, by implementing the IClientMessageInspector interface to intercept SOAP messages. On the server side, by implementing the IDispatchMessageInspector interface to intercept SOAP messages.

This is the sample on server side:

```
 public class CustomMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
     {
         public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
         {
             MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UserAgent", "http://User", "User1");
             request.Headers.Add(header);
             return null;
         }
    
         public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
         {
             MessageHeader header1 = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Testreply", "http://Test", "Test");
             reply.Headers.Add(header1);
         }
     }
     [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
     public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
     {
         public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
         {
             return;
         }
    
         public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
         {
             return;
         }
         public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
         {
             dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
         }
    
         public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
         {
             return;
         }
     }
```

This the sample on the client side:

```
         public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
 {
     public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
     {
         MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UserAgent", "http://User", "User1");
         reply.Headers.Add(header);
         return null;
     }
    
     public void BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
     {
         MessageHeader header1 = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Testreply", "http://Test", "Test");
         request.Headers.Add(header1);
     }
 }
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
 public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
 {
     public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
     {
         return;
     }
    
     public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
     {
         return;
     }
     public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
     {
         dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
     }
    
     public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
     {
         return;
     }
 }
```

Add Custombehavior above service interface to apply the message inspector.

```
   [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
         [CustomBehavior]
      public interface IDemo
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Theobald Du, I read the article of Pablo Cibraro https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15737/Globalization-Patterns-in-WCF-WS-I18N-implementati  which explains this pattern. But I am not controlling the client-side, because the clients of my WCF service are third-parties that I am not controlling at all. That's the reason why I did not implement this solution, because I am not sure if it will be callable by external third-parties, and how?

Comment: I finally ended up to try using to pass the language within the header of the request following the site http://omegacoder.com/?p=1075. It works pretty well, but maybe you can explain me if am I wrong and can try the IDispatchMessageInspector despite I do not control the clients? Thank you